# What if we want to load more instructions than the number of registers available at a time...?

Tags: assembly, nasm, instructions

I am referring to NASM.
There are some standard registers in which we load instructions before calling the kernel.

I wanted to know if at some point we want to load more instructions than the number of registers available then what should we do.....???

Newbie to assembly. Pls Help..

Comment: Can you provide an example where you think this would become an issue?

Comment: The question makes woefully little sense, you don't load an instruction into a register.  You load data, that can come from anywhere.  If you need to manipulate more data than can be stored in available registers then you need to use variables.  Locations in memory to store data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, for 32-bit system calls, if there are more parameters than we have registers (sooner than that, IME) we put the parameters in a structure and point `ebx` or `ecx` to it (`sys_socketcall`, e.g.). I'm new to 64-bit, but I imagine `rdi`... I think that's what you're asking. Got a specific example?

Answer (score 1):

There are six registers that stores the arguments of the system call used. These are the EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI,
EDI, and EBP. These registers take the consecutive arguments, starting with the EBX register. If there are more
than six arguments then the memory location of the first argument is stored in the EBX register.

Found It In A Book..!!

Answer (score 0):

Some (most?) systems use the stack to pass parameters (or pointers to parameters) beyond what registers can handle.

Answer (score 0):

I think every system has a stack, which you can use for the same.

Consider the following scenario, you already have some data in the eax, and ebx registers but also want to use sys_write, then in that you can use the stack.

Check the following code snippet demonstrating the same. : -

```
  print:
        ; you want to preserve the value stored in the eax register and the ebx register
        ; no need for extra registers to store those values, just push them onto the stack and later pop them as shown below. 
        push eax
        push ebx 
        mov eax, 4 
        mov ebx, 1
        int 0x80 
        pop ebx
        pop eax
        ret
```

Then use it as follows in your program :-

```
      mov eax, 45 ; some important value you want to preserver 
      mov ecx, msg ; msg to print. 
      mov edx, len ; length of the message to print. 
      call print ; // value of eax will be preserved.
```